# Countdown for 7 hours then show ok

Tags: php, mysql, countdown

How can I countdown for 7 hours from a variable time (I will get time from my table which is inserted with timestamp), after 7 hours from variable time I will update a table.

I need something like that

```
$time = 2013-05-18 02:00:00 // comes from database
$target = $time + 7hours // time from database +7hours will be 2013-05-18 09:00:00
$until = $target - $time
```

I need something like below code

```
if ($until > 0 ) {
    echo "you need to wait for $until hours"
} else {
    echo "time is ok"; // i will update a table
}
```

Comment: It seems like you understand how the script should work. What do you need help with?

Comment: In what context would you be using that code ? Is it a webpage that updates itself after 7 hours ? In which case, you'd also need Javascript/Ajax.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942610/php-timer-wait-30-seconds-then-run-a-command

Comment: i have a php system and i want to ignore to open this system after 7 hours when it is closed

Comment: @Orteil my start time will come from database so i can not use JS.

Comment: Where's the problem? The code's logic is great. Do you need help with getting data from DB? Doing the 7 hours addition?

Comment: @PcRestorer Check my answer, and tell me if I've missed anything

Comment: @PcRestorer You can still use AJAX to contact a PHP script and respond with a JS script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert time into string using `strtotime($time)+25200` where 7 hour `=60*60*7=25200` sec and then check and also add this file to your cron job.

Answer (score 0):

So, considering that `$database_time` is the stored time, in your db, and `$time_now` is your computers time, this message below, just echoed out:

> You Must wait 4 hours right, now

It could be done much better, but still calculates the hours from now, to db and tells you how much more, you must wait :)

```
<?php
   $date = date_create();
   $database_time = '2013-05-18 22:00:00';
   $time_now =  date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

   $check =  $database_time[11];
   $check .=  $database_time[12];
   $check2 = $time_now[11];
   $check2 .= $time_now[12];

   $time_left =  $check - $check2;
```

So, here is how you can manage your ourputs

```
 if($time_left > 0) {
   echo "You Must wait $time_left  hours right, now"; 
 }else{
   echo "Time is OK";
 }
```