# html and php redirect after login

Tags: php, html, redirect, authentication

I have the following login form which is connected to a database:

```
    <form action="login.php;" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="********">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">
    </form>
```

When I submit the form by entering a valid login, the page reloads and a pop up I made says "Logged In" - I am now logged in. However, I'd like for the page to navigate to the user's profile after the successful validation. At the moment, I have to write in the url manually.

Changing the form 'action' from 'login.php' to 'myaccount.php' does not log the user in. Is there a way to do it so that the user is logged in and redirected?

Using PHP/Html/CSS, Javascript.
Any advice would be appreciated!

P.S. Here is the PHP for the login page:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
            if (password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'])) {
            echo "<div class=\"right\">Logged in!</div>";
                    $cstrong = True;
                    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                    $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
                    DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES (\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));
                    setcookie("SNID", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                    setcookie("SNID_", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
} else {
                    echo "<div class=\"wrong\">Incorrect Password!</div>";;
            }
    } else {
            echo "<div class=\"wrong\">User not registered!</div>";
    }
} 
?>
```

Here is the PHP for the myaccount.php:

```
<?php include('./classes/DB.php');
include('./classes/Login.php');
if (!Login::isLoggedIn()) {
    die("Not logged in.");
}
if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['alldevices'])) {
                DB::query('DELETE FROM login_tokens WHERE user_id=:userid', array(':userid'=>Login::isLoggedIn()));
} else {
            if (isset($_COOKIE['SNID'])) {
                    DB::query('DELETE FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])));
                }
            setcookie('SNID', '1', time()-3600);
            setcookie('SNID_', '1', time()-3600);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: share the code where you set session after authentication ?

Comment: header('Location: your success url');

Comment: after verify process write window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"; to redirect user to another page.

Comment: the page wher you are checking the entry, there after getting `logging successfull`  do `header('Location: myaccount.php');`. Also share your php code for more clarification. Add that in your question

Comment: `action="login.php;"` well that just won't work. I honestly think that your file doesn't have a semi-colon included as its name.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are setting session after authentication, you need to redirect just after authentication like, Inside authentication method after setting session put below code and try.

```
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: /login.php');
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

share you full code and remove ; from form action "login.php".

Two method for redirect:
window.location.href = "example.com"; using javascript

header('Location: your success url'); using PHP

Comment: I've added the PHP of my login page and also php for account page. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Along with the code where you make a pop-up to say that the login was successful, include code to redirect to the profile page of the user.

You can use `<?php header('Location: profile.php') ?>` for the same

Comment: Added the relevant code, sorry bout that!

Comment: I would suggest you to use the below answer to use a timer of say, 3 seconds and then use redirection as stated in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8942644/5044480

Answer (score -1):

So the answer seems to replacing the echo line in the login PHP (echo 'Logged in';) with this line 'header('Location: logout.php');'. I also changed it to the opposite for the myaccount.php. Thanks for the suggestions guys! <3